# PHP : using Usort() inside a Loop

Tags: php, function, loops, usort

I am trying to sorting multidimensional Array.

I have the following structure in my Array:

```
array
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [events] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [task] => task1
                            [date_task] => 2018-04-02
                            [start] => 8
                            [end] => 10
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 7
                            [task] => task 32
                            [date_task] => 2018-04-02
                            [start] => 10
                            [end] => 12
                        )
                )
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
           [events] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [task] => task4
                            [date_task] => 2018-04-06
                            [start] => 11
                            [end] => 15
                        )
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [task] => task5
                            [date_task] => 2018-04-06
                            [start] => 8
                            [end] => 10
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

if i try to use Usort() function in a loop FOR or FOREACH like this :

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($MyArray); $i++) {
         usort($MyArray[$i]->events, function($a, $b) {
         return $b->start <=> $a->start;
     });
    }
```

I get this error :

> usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

how i can solve this problem ?

Comment: Check what does `$MyArray[$i]` prints. Maybe It is not what you think

Comment: what does `die(var_dump($MyArray[$i]));` output if you place it inside of the for loop before the usort?

Comment: $MyArray[$i] give first or second element of $MyArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.try to use `foreach()` over `for()`. (As it take care of indexes itself).

2.Use [passing by reference mechanism](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Do like below:-

```
foreach ($MyArray as &$MyArr) {
  foreach ($MyArr as &$MyAr) {
    if (is_array($MyAr)){
       usort($MyAr, function($a, $b) {
          return ($b->start <= $a->start) ? 1 : -1;
       });
    }
  }
}

print_r($MyArray);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/984958

Comment: Yeah but it necessary to check if $MyAr is array `if (is_array($MyAr))`  else  get error usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given
thanks for your help